# Profiling cycle time jitter in loops

Tags: loops, profiling

I'm having a little problem while making a game, and while the problem is not limited to game-programming as such, I'll express it with the specific example I'm experiencing:

As expected, I'm running the game code in a loop, controlling game logic and drawing a frame each cycle. However, I'm experiencing quite some amount of jitter in the amount of time it takes to complete each cycle. The normal cycle time varies by about a factor of two between the shortest and longest measured time, and sometimes (more rarely), larger spikes appear that take noticable time.

I would like to eliminate both. I would like to eliminate the normal jitter to make drawing smoother, and I want to eliminate the spikes because they are noticable and annoying. The problem is, I don't know what code is causing them to appear. I have tried measuring a couple of specific codepaths or collecting system resource usage, but it's only helping so far.

What I would *like* to do, is to be able to run a CPU-profiler, resetting its counter data each cycle. That way, I could easily compare from frame to frame where time is spent and which codepaths jitter more or less in themselves. But how do I do this? I'm experiencing the problem in both Java and C, and Java's `-Xprof` option and GCC's `gprof` program print measured times only from the start to end of the program lifetime (as expected). Is there any way I can dump and reset these profilers' data each cycle and/or are there some other profilers I could try that offer that ability? I also think both of them only take about 100 samples/second, which is very insufficient resolution when a frame only takes some 10-20 ms. Is there any way to turn up their sampling rate?

Alternatively, of course -- is there some completely other way I could go about to solving these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the C code, so we're not including GC time.

I assume the excess time is not happening on every frame, but pretty seldom, so any profiler that just measures aggregate times is not going to tell you much.

What I would do (and this might not be easy) is try to tell what the program is doing only when it's running over, not all the time.
If possible, at the start of each frame, I would set an alarm clock timer, set to go off a sufficient number of milliseconds later so that it would trigger somewhere in that extra time.
Then at the end of computing the frame, I would disable the timer so it wouldn't go off after the frame was finished.
It might be useful to add a small random number of milliseconds to the timer.

Then when the timer goes off, I would collect a stack sample and study it to see what the program is doing.

It's probably hard to collect samples and save them up to look at afterward.
It's probably easier and more informative to simply enter a debugger when the alarm goes off, and study the stack and what the program's doing right at that time.
To get another sample, either just resume execution or start over from the beginning.

The point being, you want to know what it's doing and why it's doing it in that excess time.
You are hoping the excess work it's doing, or some of it, is happening in that excess time.

You might need up to 20 samples before you see something interesting,
but as soon as *more than one sample* shows something happening that you didn't really realize it was doing, and you can get rid of, that will reduce the excess time usage by a significant amount.
The fewer samples you have to take before you see that, the more the time will be reduced.

There is probably more than one such issue, so don't stop after the first thing you find.
Do it over and over until you can't find anything that you could remove.

Comment: I have had something very similar to this in mind though it would have to be more complex, because I need to do it in real-time, so I would have to programmatically reconstruct the stack and save it somehow rather than just break into the debugger. That was why I was hoping that some more ready-made solution might be available. Since no answer with any such has turned up, I guess will take some time and go down this route instead.

Comment: @Dolda2000: I'm curious about the real-time requirement. It can be running flat out in real-time, then interrupt into the debugger, and that's a perfectly valid sample. Then you can do it all over again for another sample. Typically you don't need many samples (unintuitive, I know). If you see something you could remove on 2 out of 5 samples, doing so will give you a speedup of around 67%, perhaps as low as 10%, or as high as 400%, as you can see in *[this PDF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/randompausedemo/files/)*.

Comment: Well, the reason is that it's an MMO server, and unless I run it live, it won't even be loaded enough to get any interesting data; and if I run it live, I'd prefer it to be playable. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are easier ways then this - but this is how we did it:
Write your own (very simple) profiler-timer (with start/end macros) which also accepts a threshold time, and make it log when it passes the given threshold.

Wrap each top-level component in your game loop with this. That way you get logs of which components are the bottle necks.

Once you identify the component, you can use the same method to drill down into the code.

It takes some manual work (and there are probably tools that do that), but very quickly you can get to the exact location of the problem.

For example (psuedo-code):

```
while (game-loop):

  START_PROFILE(PHYSICS, 0.05);
  UpdatePhysics();
  END_PROFILE(PHYSICS);

  START_PROFILE(NETWORK, 0.05);
  UpdateNetwork();
  END_PROFILE(NETWORK);

  START_PROFILE(RENDER, 0.05);
  Render();
  END_PROFILE(RENDER);
```

Comment: This is one of the things I have already done, but it does, unfortunately, not help a lot, because my top-level functions are mainly generic dispatch functions (calling various timers, UI handling functions and such things), which dispatch to a large variety of functions, so even when I manage to detect that one of those functions spend much time, it doesn't help unless I can also detect what specific callback is spending that time and why.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to Asaf's answer by suggesting that it may be helpful to have your profile routine keep a tally of how much time has been spent in each profile-unit *since the start of the last frame*.  I don't know how readily existing profile tools can do that, but if you spin your own...

```
void START_PROFILE(PROFILE_REC *rec)
{
  if (rec->frame != total_frame_count)
  {
    rec->frame = total_frame_count;
    rec->time_before_frame = rec->total_time;
  }
  rec->time_before_last = rec->total_time;
  rec->start_time = get_precise_system_time();
}
void END_PROFILE(PROFILE_REC *rec)
{
  rec->total_time += get_precise_system_time - rec->start_time;
}
```

The above doesn't have any error-checking to ensure that the END_PROFILE calls balance out START_PROFILE calls; it will record meaningless numbers if the calls are mismatched, but error-checking would probably not be helpful without error reporting, and error reporting would add another layer of complexity.

Incidentally, if you have some tasks that can tolerate considerable jitter in their exact timing, it may be helpful to, on each frame, do all of the stuff that has to be done on that frame and then do things that can be done "whenever" until the next frame arrives.  Then handle that frame and, once that's done, return to handling the "whenever" tasks.  Depending upon your taste, you could do this with a full-fledged multi-tasking OS, or a simple round-robin stack switcher, or a set of state machines, or whatever.  I've used this approach on a game machine with 128 bytes of RAM, where being even a few microseconds "late" for a frame would cause visible display disruption, and it can be very helpful for evening out variations in timing.